# Meteor mobile app gives redirect_uri_mismatch for Google OAuth, how to fix the accounts URL?

Tags: meteor, oauth

This is all for a local development environment (in OS X) and I have:

1. local nginx with a virtual host
2. the app being served properly on myapp.dev (being proxied to localhost:3000)
3. Google app created
4. ServiceConfiguration.configurations properly setting service, clientId, loginStyle and secret

But when clicking on the google button to sign in I get:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> Application: MyApp
>
> You can email the developer of this application at:
>   blah@example.com
>
> The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google
>   did not match a registered redirect URI.

It's technically correct because since Google do not accept to put specific IP addresses for the callback (only `localhost` or some domain), I needed to setup as callback `http://myapp.dev/_oauth/google` so I can use it from the mobile device.

The problem seems to be related to accounts trying to redirect localhost:3000 instead of myapp.dev

I don't know how to setup accounts to use this domain, or maybe is a global way to tell that meteor app that it should use the `myapp.dev` domain

A solution to this would be a solution to any development environment setup for Meteor mobile apps. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`google.js` uses `absoluteUrl()` to create the callback URL so setting this in the startup of the client should give you the callback you wanted:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // Client startup method.
  Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = 'http://myapp.dev/';
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot this works for me. However cant seem to get it to work with Ngrok. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860152/how-do-use-ngrok-in-conjunction-with-google-oauth?noredirect=1#). any ideas are greatly appreciated with bounty!

Comment: @SirBT take a look, maybe what I answered there helps. good luck!