# How do I resolve the Google OAuth "redirect_uri_mismatch" error?

Tags: meteor, google-oauth, meteor-accounts, ngrok

I am failing to configure my Google OAuth for my Meteor app.

I was successful in setting it up a few weeks ago when it worked perfectly, but now all of a sudden I cant seem to correctly configure this.

I have tunneled my app via ngrok. Am going to give you a step by step illustration of the how I go towards setting this up. Kindly point out what am doing wrong and what I can do to rectify this.

I start in my terminal. I fire up the app using:

```
meteor --port 7000
```

I open up another terminal and fire up ngrok using:

```
./ngrok http 7000
```

This yields

[image: ngrok starts a tunnel to my app]

In my Meteor.startup I add the following code:

**../client/main.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // Client startup method.

  METEOR_OFFLINE_CATALOG=1;
  METEOR_PROFILE=1;

  Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl ='http://41958975.ngrok.io';
  //
});
```

In my browser console when I type:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl()
```

I get
[image: The response I get in my browser console showing the absoluteURL]

I now paste the http://41958975.ngrok.io link into the browser and get this:

[image: The entry point into the configuration of google OAuth]

Clicking on the button is followed by:

[image: the configuration of google AOuth]

Since the steps 1 to 5 have previously been done, I jump straight to steps 6, 7, and 8.

[image: The results of configuring steps 6, 7 and 8]

...and complete by pasting in the Client ID and the Client Secret

[image: The complete filled in configuration form]

then clicking on the save configuration. The results is:

[image: a successful configuration]

Now when I click on the **sign in with google** button: This pops up, just like its supposed to happen.

[image]

I click on one of the account options. This is when it all goes bazurk! I am redirected back to the **sign in with google** button (**login page**) with this error message showing

[image: Internal error message]

Looking at the terminal, I also get this error message:

[image: terminal error message]

I cant seem to get beyond this point. 
What am I doing wrong and how can I get beyond this point?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Seems like you already had this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860152/how-do-use-ngrok-in-conjunction-with-google-oauth

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to modify your `ROOT_URL` when you're running your app. The very first line of your last screenshot clearly shows it:

> `App running at: http://localhost:7000/`

Setting `absoluteUrl` on *client* won't help, because it's your *server* who tries to obtain a token.

It [uses `OAuth._redirectUri()` function](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/google-oauth/google_server.js#L102) to get `redirect_uri`, and there the [`Meteor.absoluteUrl()` is used](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87681c8f166641c6c3e34958032a5a070aa2d11a/packages/oauth/oauth_common.js#L56) (it takes `ROOT_URL` from env variables, as stated in [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl)).

Thus, your `redirect_uri` becomes `http://localhost:7000/_oauth/google` and *that* clearly mismatches with `http://41958975.ngrok.io/_oauth/google` (step #7).

To fix that you should start your Meteor application like this:

```
ROOT_URL="http://41958975.ngrok.io" meteor
```